# How can I achieve conditional page breaks in SSRS 2016

Tags: ssrs, report-builder

I am using SSRS 2016 and Report Builder. I need the page breakinging with a group to be conditional on the value of a parameter. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

[image: ReportBuilderGroupProperties]

Comment: I used to place "invisible" (no border/transparent background) text boxes or rectangles where I needed page breaks and then add the "page break before" or "page break after" on that invisible object.  This was in SSRS 2008 so not sure if it's still possible.

Comment: Thanks, I may try that if another solution doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround, which seems to work quite nicely - place a parent group of the group you want to selectively break on, then in Group Properties for *that*, group on a derived expression of either the group field, or a fixed value. And then tick the box for that grouping as per your screenshot.

e.g. Assuming a parameter called "BreakPages", and a grouping on a field called "MyGroupField", you group on:

```
=iif(Parameters!BreakPages.Value="Y", Fields!MyGroupField.Value, "None")
```

You don't need to display any fields in this special group, it'll simply use the page break setting as per your requirements..